# How to control the loading result of UIWebView's loadRequest?

Tags: ios, cocoa, unit-testing, uiwebview

I have two tests which depend on the success and failure status of loadRequest method(Some code to be verified in the delegate methods).

I want to verify the code in delegate methods without actually opening a web view evening without connecting to internet. How can I achieve it?

Thanks a lot

edited:

Maybe a mock object for UIWebView?

Comment: Is this a question about unit testing?

Comment: @michaels Yes, it's about ut..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made one object that conforms to UIWebViewDelegate and set it to UIWebView's delegate, the code is similar to the follows:

```
@interface MyObject : Object <UIWebViewDelegate>
...
@end

...

MyObject myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
webView.delegate = myObject;
```

And I can trigger the delegate methods manually:

```
[myObject webView:webView didFailLoadWithError:mockError];
[myObject webViewDidFinishLoad:webView];
```

And Of course, the webView is a mocked object.

Answer (score 0):

Just use AFNetworking and set it up like this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

You can then know if the load is successful or not. If your website always returns a 200 status code you can then just add an if / then block in the success block.

Comment: Thank you Mikael. AFNetworking has a category UIWeiView+AFNetworking can finish the work your code, but it doesn't fit the situation. Actually I want to manually control the response so that I can test the delegate methods even without connecting internet。

Answer (score 0):

[OCMock](http://ocmock.org/) is an Objective-C mocking framework that allows full mocking of classes, partial mocking of objects, as well as expectations and method stubbing.

To mock a UIWebView, you would just need to do

```
id webViewMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[UIWebView class]];
```

You could then set up expectations:

```
[[[webViewMock expect] andDo:^(NSInvocation *) {
    // Call your failure or success block
}] someMethodWithArgs:OCMOCK_ANY];
```

And inject your mock somewhere it can intercept the right calls.

You should also call

```
[webViewMock verify];
```

to make sure the expected method was invoked

Comment: OCMock is great however I've chosen Kiwi to test my code. Instead of mocking the UIWebView, I mocked a object that conforms to UIWebViewDelegate protocol. And then I sent the delegate messages to the client so that I can control result manually.